# Question about duplicate installation

Tags: updates, deb

What will happen if have installed app through repository and now the new version is out which is not in repository and i download that new version from website as deb and install it over old version of same app, what will happen, will it totally replace this old app, and what will happen when in official repo this new version arrive, when i update and upgrade in terminal my system, will this new version which is from repository run over over same version which is installed from web as deb?

Comment: oh, come on, nobody knows?